# Alt+tab raises both left and right snapped windows

Tags: 17.10, gnome-shell, application-switcher, snap-windows

Recently I switched from Fedora to Ubuntu. I like to work with half windows (for example a terminal on the left side and a chrome on the right). But I have a small issue, when I have chrome maximized and try to raise a terminal on the right side of my screen, it also brings a terminal that is on the left side.

For example:
Open windows: 2 terminals(1 left, 1 right), Google Chrome

When switching from Google Chrome to left terminal,

Desired result:
[image: Desired result]

Actual result:
[image: Actual result]

Any idea how I can stop this?